# Exception handler doesn't return correct response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, exception

I have controller method with following signature:

```
@PostMapping("/rest_upload")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
```

And I have following exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
@ResponseBody
public String handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(MultipartException e) {
    logger.warn("MultipartException occurred", e);
    String rootCauseMessage = ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e);
    return rootCauseMessage.substring(rootCauseMessage.indexOf(":") + 1);
}
```

This handler invokes when I send file with size(120MB) more than configurable maximum(100MB) But in browser I see following:

[image]

and details:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you pleaase attach controller code which handles exception?

Comment: @Datta, what do you mean?

Comment: Attach controller code also that does job of exception handling

Comment: is it not enough that this code invokes? I  posted solution

Answer (score 0):

this bean fixed my problem:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbedded() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
        // configure maxSwallowSize
        if ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)) {
            // -1 means unlimited, accept bytes
            ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
        }
    });
    return tomcat;
}
```